# python models.py syncdb does not work

Tags: python, mysql, database, django, python-2.7

Second day on my journey to install Python 2.7.2 & Django 1.5 and create my first application, and now **I can not sync models.py and update my database.**

Tools: Windows Vista, Putty SSH 
Location: Bluehost (www.bluehost.com) Server

Here is a topic that I already read but does not solve my problem:
[Why did I get error for python manage.py syncdb (IndentationError: unexpected indent)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8758025/why-did-i-get-error-for-python-manage-py-syncdb-indentationerror-unexpected-in)

The advice was about *tabs and spaces* (**indentation**) in models.py, but believe that I use the correct indentation, as you can see below (models.py).

```
from django.db import models

# Create your models here.

class posts(models.Model):

    author = models.CharField(max_lenght = 30)
    title = models.CharField(max_lenght = 100)
    bodytext = models.TextField()
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField()
```

## What I have already done:

I have installed Python 2.7.2, check:

```
username@domain.com [~]# python -V
Python 2.7.2
```

I have installed Django 1.5, check

```
username@domain.com [~]# python
Python 2.7.2 (default, Mar 27 2013, 12:07:49)
[GCC 4.4.7 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-3)] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> from django import get_version
>>> get_version()
'1.5'
>>>
```

I have installed MySQL-python-1.2.4 (**in this point I am not sure, if it works correctly**):

```
username@domain.com [~]# python
Python 2.7.2 (default, Mar 27 2013, 12:07:49)
[GCC 4.4.7 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-3)] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import MySQLdb
>>>
```

I had [problem with django-admin.py, solved it changing the .bashrc PATH entry](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15671877/django-admin-py-command-not-found-bluehost-server), and ran the colde successfully:

```
django-admin.py startproject mysite
```

Then I modified *models.py* like this (to create a simple blog):

```
from django.db import models

# Create your models here.

class posts(models.Model):

    author = models.CharField(max_lenght = 30)
    title = models.CharField(max_lenght = 100)
    bodytext = models.TextField()
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField()
```

Then I have created a ***mysql database*** and a ***user***, added user to the database and gave **all the privileges** (done all in bluehost frontend panel).

Then I modified *settings.py* like this:

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql', # Add 'postgresql_psycopg2', 'mysql', 'sqlite3' or 'oracle'.
        'NAME': 'domain_dbname',                      # Or path to database file if using sqlite3.
        # The following settings are not used with sqlite3:
        'USER': 'domain_username',
        'PASSWORD': 'password',
        'HOST': '',                      # Empty for localhost through domain sockets or '127.0.0.1' for localhost through TCP.
        'PORT': '',                      # Set to empty string for default.
    }
}
```

## Problem

Now is the time to update the database, I try this:

```
python models.py syncdb
```

And here is what I get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "models.py", line 1, in <module>
    from django.db import models
  File "/home1/domain/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/__init__.py", line 11, in <module>
    if settings.DATABASES and DEFAULT_DB_ALIAS not in settings.DATABASES:
  File "/home1/domain/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 52, in __getattr__
    self._setup(name)
  File "/home1/domain/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 45, in _setup
    % (desc, ENVIRONMENT_VARIABLE))
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Requested setting DATABASES, but settings are not configured. You must either define the environment variable DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE or call settings.configure() before accessing settings.
```

## So my question is:

Why does this line not work?

```
python models.py syncdb
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use this:

```
python manage.py syncdb
```

Comment: oh! I see, thanks. after spending so much time, I think I need a break.

`user@domain.com [~/www/domain/mysite]# python manage.py syncdb
Creating tables ...
Creating table auth_permission
Creating table auth_group_permissions
Creating table auth_group
Creating table auth_user_groups
Creating table auth_user_user_permissions
Creating table auth_user
Creating table django_content_type
Creating table django_session
Creating table django_site

You just installed Django's auth system, which means you don't have any superusers defined.
Would you like to create one now? (yes/no):`

Comment: yes, I do not have enough reputation to upvote. I have already tried to accept the answer but I should have wait for 3 minutes. Thanks again.

Comment: @Eniac did it create the posts table?